# Regex in tcl is not matching my pattern when using digits and string as a pattern

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a regex I am working with that I am trying to match the expression works in python but I am new to tcl and can't seem to get the regex to work.

```
set string"abc08_batman"
set patternOne "abc.*Batman"
set patternTwo "abc\d+.*Batman"
set patternThree "abc\d{2}.*Batman"

if {[regexp -nocase $pattern $string c]} {
   puts "Full Match 2: $c"
}
```

`patternOne` works but not good enough, `patternTwo` are what i prefer but they are not working.

The below works but I can't hardcode `08` because that defeates the purpose of using a regex.  I am now locked in to `abc08`

```
if {[regexp -nocase "abc08.*batman" $string c]} {
    puts "Full Match: $c"
}
```

Comment: *"can't seem to get the regex to work. [...] The below works"*: I am confused. If it works, what is the question?

Comment: The below works is an example of it being hard coded and working.  The `patternTwo` and `patternThree` should work as well.  But I can't hardcode the 08, defeats the purpose of a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double up the backslash to prevent it from being eaten by quote expansion.

```
set patternTwo "abc\\d+.*Batman"
```

without that, your variable's contents are `abcd+.*Batman` which shouldn't be surprising why it's not matching.

Better yet, use braces to avoid any expansions or evaluation inside them:

```
set patternThree {abc\d{2}.*Batman}
```

You need to refresh your understanding of [the Tcl syntax rules](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.html), especially Rules 4, 6 and 9.

Comment: "Put your regular expressions in braces" is a good rule of thumb in Tcl. You don't *have* to follow it, but you need to be aware of the consequences if you don't.